# Set default raster output format in qgis

Tags: qgis-2

When I save a map as image, either from the main window or from a print composer in qgis  (v 2.0.1) on debian, the default format is BW-files. Never heard about them before, never used them.. Is there any way to set another (i.e. .png) as the default image format? I have not been able to find anything in Settings / Options. Is it possible to set it directly in some configuration file? (I am using qgis both on linux and windows on the latter, the file format "sticks")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that there is a default setting. From what I can tell there are no default settings for a lot of functionality in Composer - although they are promised.

When I use this particular function, QGIS will revert to the same file extension as the last one I used. I mostly use .jpg

Comment: Thanks! If it just could stay at the same file type, in my experience, it falls back to .BW each time :-/

Comment: Perhaps the behaviour is determined by operating system. I'm running 64bit Win 7 with QGIS 2.  Maybe someone else can confirm this.

Comment: I'll check. I am running qgis on windows at work and on debian at home - at least on debian it does not stick - on windows it even sticks between sessions - you are right, I remembered wrong about having the issue on windows.